# App crash on back press after replacing fragment inside ViewPager in other tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragmentmanager

I am using a ViewPager with TabLayout, in which i have 5 pages. In the fragment of 3rd page i have a FramLayout in which i am adding a default fragment when page is created. Now there is a button on default fragment which replaces the default fragment with another fragment and adding this transaction in backstack with a tag.

**Problem:**
After replacing default fragment with new one i can press back button and the default fragment is restored, but if i change the tab say 1st without restoring default fragment and press back button on 1st tab, app is crashing.

**Log:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f1001c7 (com.xyz.android:id/manage_workers_main_container) for fragment ManageWorkersFragment{1902e37 #5 id=0x7f1001c7} 
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1293)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executePopOps(BackStackRecord.java:807)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2360)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
```

**ManageWorkerFragment.class**
This fragment contains only one function which is called from `onCreateView()` method.

```
private void setUpViewPager() {

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setTag("Fragment1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setTag("Fragment2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setTag("Fragment3"));

    manageWorkerPagerAdapter = new ManageWorkerPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(manageWorkerPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            Fragment childFragment;
            if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                childFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1_container);
                if ((childFragment instanceof Fragment1))    
                    ((Fragment1) childFragment).setMyKeyListener();

            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                childFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment2_container);
                if ((childFragment instanceof Fragment2))
                    ((Fragment2) childFragment).setMyKeyListener();
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                childFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment3_container);
                if ((childFragment instanceof Fragment3))
                    ((Fragment3) childFragment).setMyKeyListener();
            }
        }

    });

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("Fragment1");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("Fragment2");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText("Fragment3");

    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(tabLayout.getTabCount());
}
```

**Note:** I can't use `super.onBackPressed()` method inside onBackPressed() method of activity as i am handling some fragment navigation for inner fragments 
 in different tabs using onKeyDown(), i am also showing a exit conformation dialog inside onBackPressed() method of activity when there is only one entry in backstack.

Comment: No view found for id 0x7f1001c7 (com.xyz.android:id/manage_workers_main_container),see this line..I think there is no such id.

Comment: Can u post ManageWorkersFragment?

Comment: @Raghavendra updated question, please check.

Comment: @Anonymous That id is assigned to a FrameLayout inside parent fragment of default fragment (ManageWorkerFragment)